# Проблема уведомлений MIUI 12

Tags: android

Всем доброго времени!

Имеется смартфон Mi 9 Lite с прошивкой MIUI 12 (Android 11).

Проблема следующая:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Верхнее уведомление (он же медиаплеер в Telegram) никак не закрыть. Я уже все перепробовал! Даже "убивал" приложение через таск менеджер. Не помогает вплоть до перезагрузки. Есть подобные уведомления-плееры с ютуба или шазама и тд. Проблема одна: уведомления не закрываются.

С нижним уведомлением таких проблем нет.

Есть ли решение проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

1. Включите режим разработчика и проверьте, включен ли «Выключатель уведомлений (Notification Off)». Если да, то включите его.
2. Откройте Настройки > Приложения и безопасности > Разрешения приложений, выберите приложение Telegram и убедитесь, что разрешение на показ уведомлений выключено.
3. Откройте приложение Telegram и выберите «Уведомления» из меню. Убедитесь, что все настройки уведомлений (в том числе «Плейер медиафайлов») выключены.
4. Перезапустите устройство и проверьте, есть ли еще уведомления плеера.